# What is the proper way to speak about memory allocations that contribute to sizeof(class)?

Tags: c++, memory, inline, sizeof, allocation

Say we have this component object.

```
struct Component{
  int data;
};
```

Consider these two approaches a class have a component.

```
class Entity_Heap{
  //only a pointer contributes to sizeof(Entity_Heap)
  Component* HeapComponent = new Component; 
};

class Entity_Inline{
 //what is the proper way to talk about this allocation?
 //it isn't always actually on the stack... inlined memory?
 //sizeof(Entity_Inline) has sizeof(Component) contributed 
  Component InlineComponent;
};
```

I believe it may be called inline, but the "inline" word means something else specific with functions. But it appears that "inline" is the terminology unreal used.

https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/optimizing-tarray-usage-for-performance

```
TArray<Shape*> MyShapeArray;
TArray<Shape*, TInlineAllocator<16>> MyShapeArray;
```

The latter container contributes 16*sizeof(MyShapeArray) to sizeof the TArray template instantiation.
I struggle to talk about this, because I don't know the proper way.

```
void Test(){
  Entity_Inline internalComponentIsOnHeap = new Entity_Inline;
  Entity_Inline internalComponentIsOnStack;
}
```

I don't believe it called "making a component on the stack" because depending on how you instantiate Entity_Inline, it could be on the heap or it could be on the stack (see `Test` above).

**So, how would you describe to a coworker that they should change their heap allocated component, to a (inline/stack/?) allocated component?**

Comment: you confuse dynamic allocation vs automatic storage with pointer vs object. A pointer does not necessarily imply dynamic allocation: `int x = 0; int p = &x;`

Comment: I would say something like you should avoid using dynamic allocation and instead use objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: The terminology is:  `InlineComponent` is a *member variable* of `Entity_Inline`.  The other concept is [storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), where what you talk about is a bit confused about *automatic storage* versus *dynamic storage*.  Often called **stack** and **heap**, but *C++ abstract machine* has some implementation wiggle room (such as being stored in a register)